# Resizing QHeaderView columns when the widget's width changes, while still letting the user resize column widths

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qtwidgets, qheaderview

I want the user to be able to resize the columns manually,including being able to move columns behind the view's borders, but when the view resizes I want the columns to resize proportionally. Is there any neater decision than installing `resizeEvent` filter on the header view and resizing the columns manually?

Update: I couldn't even make it work with `resizeEvent`. This task is much harder than it seems to be.